# JavaScript - Execute Actions after Window.history.back()

Tags: visualforce, javascript, promises

I have a URL Button which calls a VF Page. Due to the nature of this, when the button is clicked it loads the VF Page in the URL. I need to go back to the record page and then execute an alert. However, once I go back the alert (and console statements) are never processed.

VF JS:

```
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

//some conditions...
console.log('====here 1');
window.history.back(); //back from VF Page to the record page
await delay(1000);
console.log('====here 2');  //execute lines once on record page
alert('Alert');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how browsers are designed to work. Leaving a page immediately stops all script execution and closes all network connections. You must show the alert before navigation.